# How to display the conversation between server and client with Jodd

Tags: mail-server, jodd

In upgrading from an older version of Jodd I cannot identify how to display the conversation between the server and the client. In the past I wrote:

```
smtpServer.debug(true);
imapServer.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
```

Now I tried to use:

```
smtpServer.debugMode(true);
```

but it had no effect.

I could not identify how to do this with imapServer.

I like to show the conversation to my students.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there was a bug in Jodd. The `debug` and `timeout` were not applied.

The bug was fixed in the latest commits, soon to be released.

At least, we introduced some improvements, so now on the `debug` & `timeout` methods would be applied for *all* servers, so you would not need to use different setting for the IMAP and SMTP server :)